How to stop disruption of Android phone wireless hotspot?
I have a PC that connects to the Internet using the wireless network of a Nokia XR21 hotspot.
The network is being frequently disconnected maybe by a jammer.
How can I stop the disruption?

The likelihood of a Wi-Fi + Cellular jammer being involved is very unlikely, given you can't exactly order one off Amazon. The way you describe the problem, where the hotspot works, then it doesn't work suggests you simply have a lot of signal interference. I would need to know more information.

Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/258937/44325

Jammers are used by the military, law enforcement, and by protectee details (such as outdoor events a POTUS is attending will have a jammer employed with a mutli-mile radius), however they're prohibited for civilian use. SDRs can act as jammers, albeit Occam's Razor would apply since a jammer seems the least likely cause of the issue when they're employed for short durations and everyone notices when they're used (e.g. everyone within a radius of you would be able to verify when a jammer is used).

If someone is actively jamming you, you've bigger problems. Sometimes people are not as conscious of others as they should be. If you're using a mobile hotspot you should be relatively close to your PC - its not going to have the same range as a 'proper' router.
If you're certain there's a jammer, reporting it to the relevant government body would be a good idea. I'm vaguely doubtful since there's no real point to it outside a warzone.
There's generally a few possible things - most of which are sortable by doing a site survey. My preferred solution for this is wifiman on android, but there's windows and linux wireless analyser software as well depending.
I'd consider a few things - bands (5ghz is MUCH better for this than 2.4 - and as a relatively modern phone it should do dual band), congestion, there's 3 key bands for 2.4 so I'd look at those (1, 6 and 11) , and general location (buildings can passively affect wireless as can surroundings).
If all else fails, and its just wireless - wired tethering might be an option.

Yes, wired tethering is the best and easy option I'll use. Thank you. Along with the smartphone hotspot, there are a few other wireless networks available.
But only one is not disturbed, that is, disabled. I can see this from the list of available wireless networks.
Yes the smartphone is close to the PC.
Even criminals use devices that disrupt networks.
There is nothing to justify this jamming, the whole thing is in a school.

Jammers are also used by law enforcement and by protectee details (such as outdoor events a POTUS is attending will have a jammer employed with a mutli-mile radius), however they're prohibited for civilian use. SDRs can act as jammers

Something not addressed in the other answers is that some ISPs will limit the duration of the hotspot.  It has nothing to do with jamming.  The hotspot on cellular data is not designed to be a permanent network.
You just have to restart it when it disconnects.
